# What will happen with the starcraft-2 tag if Heart of the Swarm is released?

Tags: discussion, tags

What will happen to the [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) tag once the new add-on Heart of the Swarm is released?

Will all the questions remain [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) and we add another [starcraft-2-wol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-wol) tag or will all current [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) questions be migrated to [starcraft-2-wol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-wol)?

I am asking this because once the beta is released it will be hard to separate the questions and up until now there should only be Wings of Liberty questions.

Starcraft 2 has currently about 1000 questions and the add-on will possibly have the same amount with the new campaign and all unit changes.

Comment: The former certainly

Comment: "... __if__ Heart of the Swarm is released?" Starcraft Ghost reference?

Comment: No I mean after :) I am no native speaker.

Comment: Most people nowadays refer to "Starcraft" (1) as "Brood War".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't imagine *Wings of Liberty*-only questions being the norm.  Going by Blizzard game history, expansions usually supersede the original games such that nobody generally plays the original by itself except for the campaign.

And, while I'm sure *Heart of the Swarm* will cause a spike in activity, I can't imagine a whole lot of *Heart of the Swarm*-only questions (or more specifically, *Heart of the Swarm* versions of existing questions) that aren't some form of "How did X unit/mechanic/map change in *Heart of the Swarm*?"

With that in mind, any non-campaign questions we have now should likely just be updated with the new changes brought on by the new expansion. If someone comes across a question that truly is only applicable to one expansion, can't be updated, and would only cause confusion by not being tagged with the expansion, then it should be tagged with either [starcraft-2-wol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-wol) or [starcraft-2-hots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-hots) as appropriate.

Comment: This sounds plausible. But wouldn't it be better to predict this, especially for Blizzard games. I mean they always release at least one add-on. For Starcraft 2 they even announced right from the start 2 add-ons. So right from the start we should have used starcraft-2-wol and starcraft-2 or starcraft-2-series.

Comment: The best thing to do, in my opinion, would be to go back and **add** [tag:Stacraft-2-wol] to all single player campaign questions. (Which, if I'm not mistaken, should be the entirety of questions that are not Heart of the Swarm relevant.

Comment: As of now it looks like Heart of the Swarm will be removing a couple abilities + units in the expansion, so when the game is released we'll need to retag questions about said abilities/units with starcraft-2-wol.

Comment: Problem is, right now the starcraft-2-hots tag is a synonym, this should be changed quickly, as HotS was released now.