# Do we need a separate Starcraft: Legacy of the Void tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, sub-tags

I just noticed that a [sc2-legacy-of-the-void](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sc2-legacy-of-the-void) tag has been added:

[How to pass "Evil Awoken" mission of prologue campaign on Brutal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243617/28182)

Judging from our past experiences<sup>[[1]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4740/28182) [[2]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7006/28182)</sup> with Heart of the Swarm, we have instead opted to keep using the [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) tag and not add sub-tags or expansion-specific tags.

However, some of this reasoning was based on the premise that Heart of the Swarm was an *expansion* and thus couldn't be played without Wings of Liberty, the base game. This has sinced changed, but that was one of our reasons at the time.

This is also true with Legacy of the Void: It is a standalone expansion.

I would've gone ahead and removed the use of [sc2-legacy-of-the-void](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sc2-legacy-of-the-void), but now I'm torn as to whether this is the correct course of action. Which is why I bring this to meta:

**Should Legacy of the Void have it's own separate tag or not?**

Comment: It's not the case with Heart of the Swarm anymore either. It went stand alone at some point as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) should continue to be used for all Starcraft 2 multiplayer questions. Now that the expansion is out it's what the majority of folks are playing, and all tournaments will be Legacy of the Void - you're not going to see vanilla or HOTS SC2 tournaments anymore. More importantly, though, the new SC2 meta is the Legacy of the Void meta. If someone is still playing HOTS then they're not part of the current Starcraft 2 meta, and 3 months from not you're not going to find new meta discussions or guides on the Heart of the Swarm meta, it's just assumed you own LOTV.

For questions related to the campaign, I'd say it would make sense to use a legacy of the void tag.... buuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuut as far as I can tell we didn't do this for Heart of the Swarm, and there are way too many SC2 questions to retroactively tag all WoL and HotS questions now soooooooo I say we just continue to use [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) for everything.

Answer (score 6):

**Done!**

[sc2-legacy-of-the-void](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sc2-legacy-of-the-void) is now a synonym of [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2)

This way people typing '*legacy of the void*' in the tags field will be redirected to the Starcraft 2 tag.